# Add Space Above SideBar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a sidebar which I implemented using this:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/implementing-container-containment-sliding-menu-controller/

However, I noticed that there isn't enough space above the first menu item as you can see here: [image]

Here is the code in my rootcontroller.m

```
#define kExposedWidth 200.0
#define kMenuCellID @"MenuCell"

#import "RootController.h"

@interface RootController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *menu;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *viewControllers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuTitles;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger indexOfVisibleController;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isMenuVisible;

@end


@implementation RootController

- (id)initWithViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers andMenuTitles:(NSArray *)menuTitles
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        NSAssert(self.viewControllers.count == self.menuTitles.count, @"There must be one and only one menu title corresponding to every view controller!");    // (1)
        NSMutableArray *tempVCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:viewControllers.count];

        self.menuTitles = [menuTitles copy];

        for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) // (2)
        {
            if (![vc isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
            {
                [tempVCs addObject:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc]];
            }
            else
                [tempVCs addObject:vc];

            UIBarButtonItem *revealMenuBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleMenuVisibility:)]; // (3)

            UIViewController *topVC = ((UINavigationController *)tempVCs.lastObject).topViewController;
            topVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [@[revealMenuBarButtonItem] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:topVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems]; 


        }
        self.viewControllers = [tempVCs copy];
        self.menu = [[UITableView alloc] init]; // (4)
        self.menu.delegate = self;
        self.menu.dataSource = self;

    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.menu registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:kMenuCellID];
    self.menu.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.menu];

    self.indexOfVisibleController = 0;
    UIViewController *visibleViewController = self.viewControllers[0];
    visibleViewController.view.frame = [self offScreenFrame];
    [self addChildViewController:visibleViewController]; // (5)
    [self.view addSubview:visibleViewController.view]; // (6)
    self.isMenuVisible = YES;
    [self adjustContentFrameAccordingToMenuVisibility]; // (7)


    [self.viewControllers[0] didMoveToParentViewController:self]; // (8)

}

- (void)toggleMenuVisibility:(id)sender // (9)
{
    self.isMenuVisible = !self.isMenuVisible;
    [self adjustContentFrameAccordingToMenuVisibility];
}


- (void)adjustContentFrameAccordingToMenuVisibility // (10)
{
    UIViewController *visibleViewController = self.viewControllers[self.indexOfVisibleController];
    CGSize size = visibleViewController.view.frame.size;

    if (self.isMenuVisible)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            visibleViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(kExposedWidth, 0, size.width, size.height);
        }];
    }
    else
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            visibleViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        }];

}

- (void)replaceVisibleViewControllerWithViewControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger)index // (11)
{
    if (index == self.indexOfVisibleController) return;
    UIViewController *incomingViewController = self.viewControllers[index];
    incomingViewController.view.frame = [self offScreenFrame];
    UIViewController *outgoingViewController = self.viewControllers[self.indexOfVisibleController];
    CGRect visibleFrame = self.view.bounds;


    [outgoingViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil]; // (12)

    [self addChildViewController:incomingViewController]; // (13)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]; // (14)
    [self transitionFromViewController:outgoingViewController // (15)
                      toViewController:incomingViewController
                              duration:0.5 options:0
                            animations:^{
                                outgoingViewController.view.frame = [self offScreenFrame];

                            }

                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                                 animations:^{
                                                     [outgoingViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                                                     [self.view addSubview:incomingViewController.view];
                                                     incomingViewController.view.frame = visibleFrame;
                                                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents]; // (16)
                                }];
                                [incomingViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]; // (17)
                                [outgoingViewController removeFromParentViewController]; // (18)
                                self.isMenuVisible = NO;
                                self.indexOfVisibleController = index;
   }];
}


// (19):

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.menuTitles.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMenuCellID];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.menuTitles[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self replaceVisibleViewControllerWithViewControllerAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (CGRect)offScreenFrame
{
    return CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you mean the space between `"Carrier"` and `"Cheats"`?

Comment: yes sir. i just need to add some white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give height to your section header it will add space above first row..

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    return 40; //set this value
}
```

Comment: add to your RootController.

Answer (score 0):

Your real issue here is dealing with the status bar at the top of the app.

Do you want the status bar to be hanging around while your app is in use? then you might consider bumping your whole interface down by 20pts (unless you really want the status bar to overlap your content)

Alternately you can hide the statusBar in your whole app, or just in particular viewControllers.